# How to read multiple lines of an Access SQL query using OLEDB in VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I have a Visual Basic form app that I'm developing in Visual Studio. I want to read in the data from multiple lines of an SQL query, using OLEDB. I already know how to read in the top line of the query, but don't know how read in multiple. I would probably like to save the values in a 2D array or something.

This is how I would read in 1 line, so please could you suggest a method that is similar.

```vb
    myConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=R:\Shared Drive\ICT\Database1.accdb; persist Security Info=False;"

Dim QuestionSQLCode As String
Dim QLoc, QCAns, QFAns1, QFAns2, QFans3 as String

QuestionSQLCode = (" SELECT Questions.[Question Location], Questions.[Correct Answer], Questions.[False Answer 1], Questions.[False Answer 2], Questions.[False Answer 3] FROM Questions WHERE (Questions.Category)='1: Calculating';")
myConnection.Open()

Dim QuestionCmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(QuestionSQLCode, myConnection)

Reader = QuestionCmd.ExecuteReader()

Reader.Read()

QLoc = Reader.GetValue(0)
QCAns = Reader.GetValue(1)
QFAns1 = Reader.GetValue(2)
QFAns2 = Reader.GetValue(3)
QFAns3 = Reader.GetValue(4)
MyConnection.close()
```

I will probably make an array, declared as...

> Dim QuesQueryVals(5,20) as String

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to use a [`While` loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx) (`While Reader.Read()`) but since you only have one variable for each column and don't show what you are doing with them it's hard to know what to do inside the loop.

Comment: "It ain't a duplicate because it's VB not C!!!" So there's no way that anyone else has asked this question for VB?  Don't be so defensive - duplicates are supposed to guide you to already-researched answers, not offend you.

Comment: @DStanley  Hahaha, sorry. It's just it got taken down by some guy and Stack Overflow were crap at helping me get it back up which annoyed me a bit that's all.

Comment: @DStanley I didn't want do anything apart from read them in and save them as a new value within an array.

Comment: QLoc, QCAns, QFAns1, QFAns2, QFans3   ... with each of them I would redim and add a new value, no?

Could you show me the whole loop structure please? I use Do While and For loops but never just while so any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read the entire table so you have all the questions in your code and dont have to go back and get more.  Store them in the aptly named `DataTable` and just say No to arrays.  BTW anytime you have columns named `xxx1, xxx2, xxx3` you have something wrong.  Why limit it to just 3 possible false answers?

Comment: @Plutonix That's what I want to do! ...please tell me how to read in a whole table of values (query)! Though I will stick to an array, sorry, I'm a beginner and they work for me. Cheers!

Comment: Why did you delete then undelete the code with the same code out of interest? Also please don't delete the bottom of my question saying it isn't a duplicate, either it will get taken down like last time. S.O. told me to do this!

Comment: Hmm. Is this an assignment of some sort? Another user is writing effectively exactly the same program. Not judging - just asking.